# Is the a way to delay dismissModalViewControllerAnimated?

Tags: ios

I'd like to pop a display from inside a completion block, but I also want to dismissModalViewControllerAnimated from inside the same block (but AFTER the popup completes).  Note that the popup schedules and runs after the completion block execution finishes, which means it never happens since the dismissal is synchronous...

So, a quick fix would be to find a way to schedule the dismissal asynchronously for after the popup.  Is there a chaining method?  A way to force holding async tasks to run and wait for them?

Comment: Does `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` not do what you need? You'd need to wrap the dismissal, since `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` takes a `BOOL`, but it should work.

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll check it as the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. You'll need to wrap the dismissal in a selector matching the signature required by `-performSelector:...`, since `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` takes a `BOOL`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dispatch_after instead, and it will be dismissed animatedly. check this simple sample code:

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
});
```